# How do you perform a trend analysis on a "prewhitened" time series?

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocorrelation

I would like to "prewhiten" a time series in Python, using an iteration scheme. I understand it's probably easier using R.  Instead of using the LMS method, I would like to use the Theil-Sen estimator. I'm using the method stated in Wang and Swail (2000).

We fit the following model: Yt = a + bt + Xt, where a and b are the intercept and slope parameters of Yt, and Xt is a red noise process of lag-1 autocorrelation c: Xt = cXt-1 + et

(1) compute the lag-1 autocorrelation,c of the time series Yt as a first estimate of c. If c < 0.05, the effect of serial correlation is negligible.  The the regression parameters are used as they are.

(2) Otherwise, perform the Theil-Sen estimator on the prewhitened time series Wt = (Yt - cYt-1)/(1-c)

How do you do part (2) in Python?

(3) Remove the estimated trend compoent from the original data series and reestimate c. In other words, our new estimate for c is the lag-1 autocorrelation of time series Yt - bt.

(4) Keep doing the iteration until c<0.005 or the different between the cs and bs is very small i.e. 0.0001

https://www.pacificclimate.org/~wernera/zyp/Wang%20Swail%202001%20JOC.pdf

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, TheilSenRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import RANSACRegressor
from statsmodels.tsa import stattools

x = df['ordinal'].values         
y = df[variable].values

res = stats.theilslopes(y, x, 0.95)

a = res[1]
b = res[0]

autocorr = stattools.acf(y)
autocorr_coeff = autocorr[1]
c = autocorr_coeff

if c < 0.05:
    #perform trend analysis on Wt = (Yt - cYt-1)/(1-c)
    (Yt - cYt-1)/(1-c) = a + c*b/(1-c) + b*t + et/(1-c)
    res = stats.theilslopes(-, -, 0.95)
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: How do you perform a trend analysis on a "prewhitened" time series (i.e. Wt = (Yt - cYt-1)/(1-c) )